# Let $X$ be a random variable. Then for $c>0$, how is $Pr(|X-E(X)|\geq c)=Pr(|X-E(X)|^2\geq c^2)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I found this result stated without explanation in the proof for Chebyshev inequality but the result is unintuitive to me.

Comment: If $|X-\Bbb E(X)| \geq c$, then it must be true that $|X- \Bbb E(X)|^2 \geq c^2$ and vice versa. So the probabilities of the two events are the same.

Comment: I may add that if $c<0$, the result is not true.

Comment: "but the result is unintuitive to me." If you explained why, in details, then we might reach a more interesting question...

Comment: Thanks! That was embarrassingly easy.